# Android- including custom linear layout in xml

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-custom-view

I have create a  Java class extending LinearLayout as shown below

```
    public class News extends LinearLayout{

    Context context;

     public News(Context context) {
    super(context);
     this.context=context;

     ViewFlipper viewFlipper=new ViewFlipper(context);
     viewFlipper.setLayoutParams(this.getLayoutParams());
    this.addView(viewFlipper);

    }
```

Now is it possible to include this into xml layout like this:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.android.apis"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">



        <com.example.android.apis.view.LabelView
                android:background="@drawable/green"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                app:text="Green" app:textColor="#ffffffff" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: yes what's the problem ..........?

Comment: Thank you because i dint find any documentation which said i could do this... I was not aware..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 <com.yourcompanyname.projectname.News<<<change here and check path is proper
                android:background="@drawable/green"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                app:text="Green" app:textColor="#ffffffff" />
```

- [See this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you should also override the other constructors as well.

```
<com.yourproject.package.News
    android:background="@drawable/green"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    app:text="Green" app:textColor="#ffffffff" />
```

Also, xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.android.apis" need to be update to your application package as well.

Comment: Yes i just posted tat as an example... I understood that. But i dint get what u meant by override other constructors... which other constructor u mean

Comment: I think you need to *not override* but implement Constructor with AttributeSet so that it pass attributes to LinearLayout probably. Or maybe it's optional, in that case I'm sorry for bringing that up.